# When we use ngOnInit in services?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

When we use ngOnInit in services?

For exmaple I need to listen Observer inside service:

```
this.eventService.subscribe((data) => {

});
```

Where better place this code inside constructor or ngOnInit?

Comment: subscribe in a service?? I don't know yours requeriments but in general the services must not subscribe, are the components who subscribe to services

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is a angular life cycle hook. They are only available within component/directives. In services, you can't use them. 
So need to use this under the constructor.

```
constructor(){

  this.eventService.subscribe((data) => {

  });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pust observer in `ngOnInit`. the firrence is:

- `constructor` is used when the object is instantiated and you need it when you have some fields that must be initialitated.
- `ngOnInit` is  is a life cycle hook called by Angular when the component is created

Comment: Service has `ngOnInit` or only components?